# VBA range setup

Tags: excel, vba, range

I am a beginner in VBA coding and I would like to ask, probably, a basic question.

I have a file where I am putting the current date every day in the same row. Under the date there are data to be pasted from another file. I was able to match the data format and connect files each other, but how to set up a range for data, to have them pasted right below the proper date?

Default code from macro recorder is following

```
Range("B4").Select
```

Visualisation

[image]

Comment: `Range("B4").Offset(1).Select` if you mean to select the cell below. You should also post the code you've already got and describe in more detail what you're trying to achieve. You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66492715/edit) your post at any time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have these dates in the same row (eg. row 1) you can go to the last nonempty cell by code:

```
Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Select
```

you are now in the cell with the latest date. Then you can go one cell down:

```
selection.offset(1,0)
```

Offset(1,0) function means that from the place where you are you want to go one row below and 0 columns right/left.

You can compile these two lines in one:

```
cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).offset(1,0).paste
```